Getting dependency errors after creating a new Flutter project
All of a sudden, after I create a new flutter project, I immediately get this error message.

Resolving dependencies...
flutter_lints 2.0.3 (4.0.0 available)
lints 2.1.1 (4.0.0 available)
matcher 0.12.16 (0.12.16+1 available)
material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.12.0 available)
meta 1.10.0 (1.15.0 available)
path 1.8.3 (1.9.0 available)
test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.2 available)
web 0.3.0 (0.5.1 available)
Got dependencies!
8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try flutter pub outdated for more information.

So I run through all the recommended commands, and the error message for flutter_lints and lints go away, but the others remain.
BTW, for environment I'm using: sdk: '>=3.2.6 <4.0.0' The project also runs ok on the iPhone Simulator.
Thanks for any help!
